# How can I rewrite this while loop in a JSLint-approved way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jslint

Looking at the the "Streams 2 & 3 (pull) example" from: https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra#walk

```
var items = [] // files, directories, symlinks, etc
var fs = require('fs-extra')
fs.walk(TEST_DIR)
  .on('readable', function () {
    var item
    while ((item = this.read())) {
      items.push(item.path)
    }
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    console.dir(items) // => [ ... array of files]
  })
```

Latest version of JSLint complaints about the `while`:

```
Unexpected statement '=' in expression position.
                while ((item = this.read())) {
Unexpected 'this'.
                while ((item = this.read())) {
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write this in a JSLint-approved way. Any suggestions?

(Note: I'm aware there are other JSLint violations in this code ... I know how to fix those ...)

Comment: Did you mean to use `==` for comparison?

Comment: if you are comparing shouldn't it be `while ((item === this.read()))`

Comment: @A.J No, it's an assignment that is expected to return a truthy value here. And JSLint doesn't like these, there's too many things going on in a single set of expressions.

Comment: I think OP is relying on `read()` returning a falsy value when there's no more data left in the readable.

Comment: I'd recommend to use ESLint which is configurable, instead of JSLint.

Comment: I'm amazed that you didn't first fix the total absence of any `;` and the use of `'...'` instead of `"..."` (which jslint seems to care so much about) before posting this code which is a nightmare for jslint :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're really interested in writing this code like Douglas Crockford (the author of JSLint), you would use recursion instead of a `while` loop, since there are tail call optimizations in ES6.

```
var items = [];
var fs = require("fs-extra");
var files = fs.walk(TEST_DIR);
files.on("readable", function readPaths() {
    var item = files.read();
    if (item) {
        items.push(item.path);
        readPaths();
    }
}).on("end", function () {
    console.dir(items);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would you get rid of the `this` ?

Comment: @boozedog Updated, to remove `this`